# CXF follow redirected url

Tags: jakarta-ee, redirect, soap, cxf, jboss7.x

Good morning

I got an issue where I have an URL link and receiving soap message from it. The URL was static at first but lately it redirects me to another URL so when I try my application it gave me EOF prolog error.

So I know that the redirection of the URL missed up my application but I know that I could make CXF follow the redirection.

what I need is an example of how I make CXf follow redirection of a URL because I tried in every way I know and I didn't know how to make it,

I'm using Java EE, JBoss 7

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Auto-redirection is not enabled by default in HTTP client policy in CXF HTTP conduit.

Using code:

```
SOAPService service = new SOAPService(wsdl, serviceName);
WsdlInterfaceClass port = service.getPort(portName, WsdlInterfaceClass.class);
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
final HTTPClientPolicy policy = httpConduit.getClient();
policy.setAutoRedirect(true);
```

Using Spring:

```
<http:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world}HelloWorld.http-conduit">

  <-- .. -->

  <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>

</http:conduit>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto-redirecting for Apache CXF JAX-RS Client, please add the http.autoredirect property to the JAX-RS Client config.

client.property("http.autoredirect", true);

Other properties that be set in the client config, can be found in the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl class.

Comment: Thanks. To avoid boxing, you should use Boolean.TRUE instead.